# C++ template parameter as function call name

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

In C++, is possible to make something like this:

```
class A 
{
public:
   template <typename ClassType, typename MethodName, typename ...Args>
   static func()
   {
       ClassType t = GetPtr<ClassType>();
       t->MethodName(GetArg<Args>()...);
   }
}

A::func<B, sum, double, double>(); //should call B->sum(double, double)
A::func<C, sum2, std::string, double, double>(); //should call C->sum2(std::string, double, double)
```

where `GetPtr` and `GetArgs` are working methods to obtain pointers from dictionary.

Comment: Where are you planning to get arguments for `MethodName` call?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan There are passed from Lua. Each `GetArg<T>` call pop one argument from stack. I have template specialization methods for different `T`

Comment: MethodName is a type. From the look of things you need a member function pointer. Template template maybe?

Comment: @DeiDei that sounds like hell. Boost has gone through hell already and has a best of hell ready to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make use of non-type template parameters like:

```
template <typename ClassType, typename MethodType, MethodType MethodName, typename ...Args>
static void func() {
    ClassType t = GetPtr<ClassType>();
    (t->*MethodName)(GetArg<Args>()...);
}
```

to use it as follows:

```
A::func<B, double (B::*)(double,double), &B::sum, double, double>();
```

When your compiler will support c++17 your code could get even shortened:

```
template <typename ClassType, auto MethodName, typename ...Args>
static void func() {
    ClassType t = GetPtr<ClassType>();
    (t->*MethodName)(GetArg<Args>()...);
}
```

With usage:

```
A::func<B, &B::sum, double, double>();
```

Comment: I am getting  `'MethodName': is not a member of 'B'` (I have created `class B { public: double sum(double a, double b) { return a + b; } }`)

Comment: @MartinPerry try this one

Comment: Great.. working. Exactly what I was lookinf gor. Thank you.

Comment: @WF It is working as expected if all arguments are the same (eg. double, int...), but if I have this `A::func<B, &B::sum, int, double>();`, the ordder of  parameters in `(t->*MethodName)(GetArg<Args>()...);` is not specified and I can end up with this `(double, int)` insetad of `(int, double)`

Comment: @MartinPerry are you sure it is caused by the the non-type template parameter?

Comment: @MartinPerry as a side note you could try to deduce the `Args` types from the member function `MethodName` to not to supply this information to your `func` twice...

Comment: @WF Well, this is where my knowledge ends

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asked, but I suppose you can do someting like

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Class, typename Method, typename ... Args>
void callMethod (Class & c, Method m, Args ... args)
 { ((&c)->*m)(args...); }

int main()
 {
   std::vector<int>     v;
   std::array<int, 5U>  a;

   callMethod(v, &std::vector<int>::size);
   callMethod(v, static_cast<void (std::vector<int>::*)(int const &)>
                    (&std::vector<int>::push_back), 7);
   callMethod(a, &std::array<int, 5U>::fill, 3);

   std::cout << v.back() << std::endl; // print "7"

   for ( auto const i : a )
      std::cout << i << std::endl; // print "3" five times
 }
```

Observe that with `push_back()` method of `std::vector<int>`, you need a cast (`static_cast<void (std::vector<int>::*)(int const &)>`) to resolve the overloading ambiguity (there are two `push_back()` in `std::vector<int>`)

Not sure about the use of `GetPtr()` and `GetArgs()`, but I suppose you can use `callMethod()` as follows

```
callMethod(GetPtr<B>(), &B::sum, GetArgs<double>(),
           GetArgs<double>());
callMethod(GetPtr<C>(), &C::sum2, GetArgs<std::string>(),
           GetArgs<double>(), GetArgs<double>());
```

Answer (score 1):

as the word `typename` suggests, no, this won't work (generally), but:

you can basically just create a class that overloads `operator(.)`, and do the calling inside the overloaded operator.

In fact, `Boost::bind` does exactly that and allows you to get "functor" objects that you can pass around at runtime as objects.