# C++11 - template std::enable_if and std::result_of

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have created this to specialize template for void / non-void methods

```
template <typename ClassType, 
        typename MethodType, MethodType MethodName,         
        typename std::enable_if <std::is_same<void, std::result_of<decltype(MethodName)(ClassType)>::type>::value> ::type* = nullptr
>
static int function()
{
   //void
   //....
}



template <typename ClassType, 
        typename MethodType, MethodType MethodName,         
        typename std::enable_if <!std::is_same<void, std::result_of<decltype(MethodName)(ClassType)>::type>::value> ::type* = nullptr
>
static int function()
{
   //non-void
   //....
}

//And I want to call it like this
function<Foo, void (Foo::*)(void), &Foo::Print>();
function<Foo, int (Foo::*)(void), &Foo::Print2>();
```

(Based on this answer: [C++ template parameter as function call name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072627/c-template-parameter-as-function-call-name))

Hovewer, this gives me bunch of errors (MSVC 2015). If I run this inside of

```
template <typename ClassType, 
        typename MethodType, MethodType MethodName      
>
static int print()
{
    std::cout << "C: " << std::is_same<void, std::result_of<decltype(MethodName)(ClassType)>::type>::value << std::endl;
}
```

I got `true` result.

Is it possible to "create" function with specialisation for void / non-void results of `MethodName` ?

Comment: Just a sidenote, if you want to check for void just use is_void, its shorter than is_same<void, ...>

Comment: @AdrianLis I know, I have tried that too, but with the same outcome (plus in some cases I dont want to test for void, this is just to simplify the example ;-))

Comment: You haven't posted the error you get but I can see you are missing `typename` keyword before `std::result_of<...>`

Comment: If you want it to be a pointer to member function as a template argument then the template ClassType as argument to MethodName makes no sense to me. Is this correct?

Comment: @AdrianLis You are right, but I am using it inside the body as template for another methods, so its more readable for me (at least, yet)

Comment: @MarekRogosz Yes.. that was it. Stupid mistake. Post it as answer.

Comment: With missing `typename` fixed, that works [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b838405f791e617b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just miss `typename`.

As alternative I suggest:

```
template <typename F, F f> struct function_helper;

template <typename C, typename ... Ts, void (C::*m)(Ts...)>
struct function_helper<void (C::*)(Ts...), m>
{
    int operator()() const { /* void implementation*/ }
};

template <typename C, typename Ret, typename ... Ts, void (C::*m)(Ts...)>
struct function_helper<Ret (C::*)(Ts...), m>
{
    int operator()() const { /* non-void implementation*/ }
};

template <typename F, F f>
static int function()
{
     return function_helper<F, f>{}();
}
```

With usage

```
function<void (Foo::*)(), &Foo::Print>();
function<int (Foo::*)(), &Foo::Print2>();
```

or

```
function<decltype(&Foo::Print), &Foo::Print>();
function<decltype(&Foo::Print2), &Foo::Print2>();
```

With C++17, we may get rid of first template argument with `template <auto f> struct function_helper;`

Answer (score 2):

This compiles fine under GCC

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template <typename ClassType, typename MethodType, MethodType MethodName>
static auto function()
  -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<typename std::result_of<MethodType(ClassType)>::type>::value, int>
{
   //void
   //....
}

template <typename ClassType,  typename MethodType, MethodType MethodName>
static auto function()
  -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_void<typename std::result_of<MethodType(ClassType)>::type>::value, int>
{
   //non-void
   //....
}
```

I am not sure if this is what you are looking after but I moved enable_if to return type using the arrow syntax, this looks just more clean to me. Also why bother using decltype on MethodName since you already have the type as MethodType. Also result_of needs typename before accessing the type.

This as above does compile although without possible usage I am not sure if this is what you are after.

note: `std::enable_if_t` is avaialble in C++14 if you can't use that change to `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` instead.